# Getting NODE JS to run on specific Port

Tags: node.js, nginx, forever

So I have an application that is executed by forever.

```
forever start -l log.log -e err.log -o out.log -a /[path to node js]
```

I have it set to listen on port 3015 but when I run netstat -a, the port is not being listened on.

I'm using NGINX to forward all 80/443 requests to 127.0.0.1:3015 but it gives a 502 Bad Gateway error as it's unable to deliver to port 3015.

I'm unsure of how to get this app to listen on 3015!!!

EDIT: This is what is in the js app

```
program
  .version(version)
  .option('-p, --port <port>', 'Port to run on', 3015)

https.createServer(ssl, app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port %s in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});
```

EDIT: Here is what it says in the error log:

```
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
error: Forever restarting script for 1 time
```

Comment: Are you sure that `node` is executing your script? Are you certain it executed the `.listen(3015)` to actually sit and listen for communication? Anything in `err.log` or `out.log` that would suggest issues?

Comment: You must post a code snippet or we can't help you. When you say "have it set to listen", what does that mean? To get a node script to listen on a port, you write code to start a server on that port.

Comment: Added code snippet.  To clarify - why isn't the node js application opening port 3015 to be listened on?  This is the only thing I see:

error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1

Comment: Well, what does is say in your log?

Comment: If this is all of your app then where does program, app, and ssl come from ? Does it work when not starting it with forever?

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but I think I found the answer: I was in a different directory when executing the forever command and I thought I could include the path to the js file.  I guess when executing the script, you need to be in the directory of the application

Answer (score 0):

You should check for errors in the "listen" callback function. Something like this:

```
https.createServer(ssl, app).listen(app.get('port'), function(err){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Express server listening on port %s in %s mode', app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
});
```

And tell us if an error occured.